# Where can I read more about Leshys?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters

Bestiary 3 talks about leshys — plant creatures you can grow yourself — but there is not much info in Bestiary 3 on them. I'm especially interested in learning more on how they're created and other practical details I'll need as GM for a player character Druid that wants to cultivate a large number of them.

Are leshys described in greater detail anywhere?

Comment: Thank you for editing my question so it reads better. This is a good way of putting it.

Answer (score 3):

Leshys in general can be read about [here, in the SRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/plants/leshy-template), or in the Bestiary 3 entry.  The entry does in fact cover the requirements, there just aren't very many.  You also may have missed the overview section, which is at the beginning and not attached to any specific Leshy.  Leshys are nearly free, take a very small amount of time to craft, and have powerful abilities (like sentience) as compared to constructs of roughly the same CR.  Consider carefully the ramifications before integrating Leshys into your world.

The specific Leshy entries are linked in the SRD and follow the general template in Bestiary 3.